# samba Ldap password restriction

Tags: samba, openldap

I'm trying to change the password for Ldap users using Samba. i'm using smbldap-tools-0.9.6 . I use the command smbldap-passwd in terminal. I can able to change the password. But i want to password restrictions like password must be minimum 6 characters and it should return error if it goes beyond 90 days like that.

Please guide me with some steps...

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with a combination of the smbk5pwd, password exop and slapo_ppolicy on OpenLDAP + Samba setups